# Fedora changed hostname

Tags: fedora, dual-boot, hostname

I am running Fedora 31 and Windows 10 on my Lenovo laptop. Everything has been running smoothly between the two systems for over half a year now, but turning on my machine today I was shocked to find that the bash prompt, containing the hostname, has changed and the new hostname is the same as the one set for the Windows OS.

I am lost on why this happened and how the two systems could have communicated in such an unexpected way and I am unsure how to proceed with further investigations. Of course, a reboot has been attempted and yielded no change at all. Is this a known bug?

Answer (score -3):

I am not sure of the cause, but you can try fixing it by writing the desired host name as a single line in the file /etc/hostname and rebooting.

Comment: The answer is based on obsolete knowledge. The correct way to change a hostname is by using hostnamectl. In any case, the questioner is interested in the root cause of the problem, not a workaround.